# Sencha Touch 2.x: Running "sencha app build native" makes my app behave strangely

Tags: extjs, cordova, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

My app works as expected when I run it in the browser on my PC or mobile device, but when I run `sencha app build native` which is supposed to minify the app and bring all the files together, I don't get the full functionality of the app. Specifically, CSS rules I defined in the `app.css` file are gone, and some buttons don't work as expected. I get no errors at all when building, and no warnings.

The strange thing is the app worked a few revisions back, but lately it hasn't been behaving properly when I build it. In fact not only does the build seem to alter some of the files, but my original `app.css` is altered after running the build command and I always have to revert back to the old one. What could be causing this type of behavior?

**EDIT:** The broken features were the result of simple errors in code that didn't manner for some reason prior to building the app. I was building native then testing on iPhone and Android, and didn't realize that I can run `sencha app build production` and test it on my web server! This allowed me to use Chrome Dev Tools to find the problem in my JS code.

The CSS issues were covered by the answer below! Specifically, I decided to define all my rules in a custom.css file and left app.css untouched.

Comment: You should use resources/sass/app.scss file to change app style. when you build sencha app i think it rewrites app.css file based on app.scss file

Comment: It doesn't help if you say that "a few revisions back it worked". It would help if you said what changes you have done since then. That said, @Viswa is right, app.css gets overwritten by the build based on your app.scss file.

Comment: @Anubis There are far too many changes to list, which is why I asked the question the way I did. Specifically, I was hoping to learn if something was overwriting the app.css file (which Viswa and shepsii confirmed for me) which would help me realize that my previous revisions did not have any css rules defined in that file, which seems to be the case. I have managed to remedy the situation and learn something new!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your css should go in the .scss file at resources/sass. Everytime you run sencha app build native, it runs compass compile, which compiles the .scss file into the .css file. The docs cover how this side of sencha touch works here: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.0/#!/guide/theming

Comment: This did it for me, thanks! I also found out that I can put my css rules in a new file and leave the app.css untouched.

Comment: You don't need an additional file, just add the rules to `app.scss`, so you'll get css compression. If you really want modular stylesheets you can `@import 'additional';` in `app.scss` and add an `_additional.scss` file in the same folder.

Comment: I see. I'll take advantage of the compression and move my css rules to app.scss.

Comment: Have a look at what else you can do in scss too (check out the docs for sass and compass). It's way easier and more efficient to write sass that compiles to css, than it is to write raw css.

Comment: Then my build process is broken. After compass compiles my css it works fine. But then after building with "sencha app build production" a set of icons disappear.